# React useEffect chaining for async actions with firebase snapshot

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

What it is : a one to one chat using Firebase
How it is done: we have "chatIds" column, and "messages" column in Firebase Firestore, after you query "chatIds" in first useEffect, you can you use the returned list of ids from there to retrieve "messages" and map over them.
The problem: it seems the second useEffect does not trigger every time after ,,chatIds" changes in order to rerender the component and i cannot achieve ,,one to one chat" experience.

Many thanks

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

const Child = ({ user }) => {
 
 const [idChat, setIdChat] = useState(null)
 const [meessages, setMessages] = useState(null) 

 useEffect( ()=> {
   db.doc().get().then( value => setIdChat(value) ) // async action: some value received after 
                                                    // querying Firebase DB 
   
 }, [user]}  

 useEffect( ()=> {
   const docMessages = [];
   idChat.messages.map( message => {
      db.doc(`message/${message.id}`).get().then( res => docMessages.push(res.data()))
   })
   setMessages(docMessages)
 }, [idChat]}
  
 return{
     <div>{messages.map( m => <div>{m.sender}:{m.text}</div>)}</div>
 }
}

exoport default Child
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setMessages(docMessages)` function runs before the messages are resolved. You need to resolve the messages first and then update the state:

```
   const messages =  idChat.messages.map(async message => (await db.doc(`message/${message.id}`).get()).data());
   setMessages(messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to the `useEffect` Hook. It allows to run the code when `idChat` is not `null` and prevent to run it on first render:

```
 useEffect(()=> {

    if(idChat){

        const docMessages = [];

        idChat.messages.map( message => {
            db.doc(`message/${message.id}`).get().then(res => docMessages.push(res.data()));
        });

        setMessages(docMessages);

    }

 }, [idChat]);
```

Note: Be careful with the bracket at the end of the `useEffect` Hook. It should be a parenthesis.